# Wrong number of arguments error (0 for 1) in Ruby on Rails 4 when creating a form for user submission

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms

at the moment I am attempting to create a form for my website that will allow for users to input information and then the information with be POST'ed to my database for storage. I am a new ruby on rails developer so keep that in mind.

I was able to get to the point where the user could see the form and type in information but once they hit the submit button I recieve an error, and that error is

> ArgumentError in StudentsController#create
>     wrong number of arguments (0 for 1) in app/controllers/students_controller.rb:13:in `create'

The parameters that were sent were the following

```
{"utf8"=>"✓",
 "authenticity_token"=>"bLalQ9Ek5ziaGiGHj03AGPCTIABAgcT+o4eTgN44qv44dxNDlrGA0h2u5BSTQVTMh+YgA/mLPQee05lT7mxCsw==",
 "student"=>{"first_name"=>"Andrew",
 "last_name"=>"Terra"},
 "commit"=>"Submit"}
```

Below is my students_controller.rb file.

```
class StudentsController < ApplicationController

def index
    @students = Student.all
end


def new
    @student = Student.new
end

def create
    @student = Student.new(params.require[:student])
    if @student.save
        redirect_to students_path
    end
end

def destroy
    @student = Student.find_by_id(params[:id])
    if @student.destroy
        redirect_to students_path
    end
end

end
```

Below is my views/students/_form.html.erb file

```
<%= form_for @student do |f| %>
<p>
    <%= f.label :first_name %>
    <%= f.text_field :first_name %>
</p>
<p>
    <%= f.label :last_name %>
    <%= f.text_field :last_name %>
</p>
<%= f.submit "Submit" %>
<% end %>
```

Below is my /views/students/index.html.erb file

```
<%= link_to "Create new information", new_student_path %> <br /> <hr>

<% @students.each do |fo| %>
    Firstname: <%= fo.first_name %> <br />
    Lastname: <%= fo.last_name %> <br />

    <%= link_to "Delete info?", student_path(student), :data=>{:confirm=>"Are you sure ?"}, :method=> :delete %>

    <br />
    <hr>

<% end %>
```

Finally, here is my /views/students/new.html.erb file

```
Enter new info
<hr>
<%= render :partial => "form" %>
```

And I did remember to put `resources :students` in my routes file. I searched around and found other people who had previously had this problem but none of the solutions worked on the code that I have written. So I was wondering if anyone could point me in the direction of where the bug is and how exactly I can fix it. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add a new private method:

```
private
def student_params
   params.require(:student).permit(:first_name, :last_name)
end
```

And then as said before change your create method to:

```
def create
    @student = Student.new(student_params)
    if @student.save
        redirect_to students_path
    end
end
```

I recommend reading the documentation on Strong Parameters - to better understand how they work.  https://github.com/rails/strong_parameters

Comment: Thank you very much, this seemed to work. And now I am able to create a user seamlessly. Is there anything in my question that I could have fixed or been more explicit about?

Answer (score 0):

You have to change 
params.require[:students] to params.require(:students)

But this is still not good way to handle your params for create action, you should add private method student_params to your controller where you would whitelist your params. Like this:

`def student_params
  params.require(:student).permit(:first_name, :last_name)
end`

Here you can find more about it,
http://edgeapi.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/StrongParameters.html